# How to display cached uploaded image in tmp/uplodas directory using Carrierwave S3 and Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: heroku, carrierwave, image-uploading, sidekiq

I am using Carrierwave + carrierwave_backgrounder + Sidekiq + Heroku to upload images. The upload works fine. When the upload form is submitted, I need to display the uploaded image, but background job is still processing it, so the page only displays the file name, I have to wait the background job is done, refresh the page to see it. How can I display a temp uploaded image when the page finish loading?

I know I can config the cache_dir to store a tmp image and will be deleted afterwards, like this:

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

Can I render this tmp image? If so, how do I render this in the view? I want to avoid using default_url in the uploader

I am using process_in_background :avatar in the model

Thanks!!

Comment: I doubt there is something like it with that I presume ur best bet (perhaps you know it ) `default_url` also make sure you set `move_to_cache` `move_to_store` could improve ur background processing experience because seem like u r file are quite large

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to define the `default_url` method in your uploader class.

Ex:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a way I can display the cached uploaded image in the tmp/uploads?